# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION

Tags: errors, parse

I just moved my site from one server to another, both on bluehost

But i am getting this error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in /home2/energzk2/public_html/wp-content/themes/energy/functions/contact.php on line 3
```

Here is the  few lines of code for the file

```
<?php 
/*Add meta boxes to contact page*/
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_page', function( \WP_Post $post ) {

    global $post;

    if(!empty($post)){
        $pageTemplate = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true);

        if($pageTemplate == 'page-contact.php' ){
        add_meta_box('contact_meta_1', 'Contact Details', 'contact_details', 'page', 'normal', 'high');
        add_meta_box('contact_meta_2', 'Social  Details', 'social_details', 'page', 'normal', 'high');
        add_meta_box('contact_meta_3', 'Footer  Details', 'footer_section', 'page', 'normal', 'high');
        add_meta_box('contact_meta_4', 'Copyright', 'copyright', 'page', 'normal', 'high');

    }
   }
 },1);
```

I tried the solution given by @Howdy_McGee and it worked. But i am getting this warning

```
Warning: Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in /home2/energzk2/public_html/wp-content/themes/energy/functions/contact.php on line 19
```

Comment: Please note that typically questions regarding syntax errors aren't usually WordPress specific but PHP specific and tend to be closed as [Off-Topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). In the end, these types of questions are better suited for [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is called an [Anonymous Function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) and is only supported in later versions of PHP, specifically **5.3.0 and later**. If I were a betting man I would say your server has an earlier version of PHP. Try this instead:

```
/*Add meta boxes to contact page*/
function contact_metaboxes( \WP_Post $post ) {
    global $post;

    if( ! empty( $post ) ) {
        $pageTemplate = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true);

        if($pageTemplate == 'page-contact.php' ){
            add_meta_box( 'contact_meta_1', 'Contact Details', 'contact_details', 'page', 'normal', 'high' );
            add_meta_box( 'contact_meta_2', 'Social  Details', 'social_details', 'page', 'normal', 'high' );
            add_meta_box( 'contact_meta_3', 'Footer  Details', 'footer_section', 'page', 'normal', 'high' );
            add_meta_box( 'contact_meta_4', 'Copyright', 'copyright', 'page', 'normal', 'high' );
        }
   }
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_page', 'contact_metaboxes', 1 );
```

Comment: thanks a lot . I also thought so. But i checked and php version is 5.4.24. I ll try your solution , but can do it now as all of a sudden domain name is pointing to the old site hosted on wordpress.com. Will try your solution and let you know

Comment: Or, a better solution is to get with BlueHost and ensure the right version of PHP....

Comment: @cale_b sure i ll do so...  But can it be , that i am seeing wrong version in cpanel?

Comment: Certainly that is possible.

Comment: @terminator If you have more information, please edit your original question and add that info, the comment section is not the proper place for that. If you keep running into these errors, maybe it's time to contact a developer ( or BlueHost as cale_b suggests ) to sort these out, who knows how many errors you'll keep running into because of outdated versions of PHP.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee sure i think ya you are right all the issue is due to outdated version. Apologies to bother you again anyways thank you